# Parsing a delimited string

Tags: ada

I need to implement a linked list in ADA that has a node of 3 parts that include:
1. name of the node
2. value of the node
3. name of the next node

I need to take inputs from user, with each part of the node ending with a ";"

e.g

This is what input on command line must look like

a;22;b
b;33;c
c;43

The LL ends at c. So we have nothing after the value

I can implement a LL, but how am I supposed to read the ';' in the input and assign it to the respective node dynamically to build the linked list???

Comment: What is supposed to happen if, for example, the command line input was `a;22;x b;33;c; c;43`? And what should happen if the data was `b;33;c c;43 a;22;b`? I’m not at all sure that a linked list is the right way to go about this.

Comment: It is assumed that the user will specify the nodes in order...and enter will be pressed after he types in the name of the next link node. I need to implement it as a linked list only.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is... are you stuck trying to figure out how to parse an input string in Ada?  There are a lot of procedures and functions in [`A.4.3`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html) that should be helpful, and the "slice" notation is how you can extract a substring.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried anything yet, but that can't be true?  Can you show us how far you've come?

Comment: Is this by any chance homework?  If it is, remember to cite your sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a string `Input` which contains one of your nodes' data (for example, `”a;22;b”`), you can find the position of the first semicolon using

```
First_Semicolon : Natural :=
  Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index (Source => Input,
                           Pattern => ";”,
                           From => Input'First);
```

and the last semicolon using

```
Last_Semicolon : Natural :=
  Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index (Source => Input,
                           Pattern => ";",
                           From => Input'Last,
                           Going => Ada.Strings.Backward);
```

The node `Name` is then the substring of input from the beginning to one before the first semicolon,

```
Input (Input'First .. First_Semicolon - 1)
```

If `First_Semicolon` and `Last_Semicolon` are equal, then you have the case where there’s no next node name, and the node `Value` is

```
Natural'Value (Input (First_Semicolon + 1 .. Input'Last))
```

but if they aren’t equal the next node name is present, so the node `Value` comes from the part of `Input` between the semicolons,

```
Natural'Value (Input (First_Semicolon + 1 .. Last_Semicolon - 1))
```

and the `Next_Node_Name` from the remainder of `Input`,

```
Input (Last_Semicolon + 1 .. Input’Last)
```

Obviously there’s no error checking here, and there’s a lot that could go wrong. I’ve not discussed creating the linked list, either, because you say you can do that (personally I’d use `Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists` ...)